# Two different pages of Google.com

Tags: networking

I was reading somewhere that http:// 74.125.236.65 is the IP Address of a google server. Now if i enter this IPaddress as a URL in browser, i am reaching to a standard Google page, but when i enter www.google.com it takes me to a page with some doodle on it. Why is this difference, should i assume that both time i am reaching to different web server? if so than which is local web server to me( i mean location specific(i think 2nd one).

May looks like a silly question, but i am curious.

Comment: There is probably a better stackexchange site for this question, but the basic answer is that Google has more than one server and more than one IP address linked to the domain name "google.com", and somewhere along the line the best server for your location is chosen to connect to when you connect to google.com, but when you connect by IP you get a specific server (which when you tried may not have been updated to have the new site look).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using chrome hit

> ctrl+shft+i

to turn on the debugger. The network tab of your debugger will show all the request and response headers. This can give you information. Basically when you hit google.com its a domain name, google might do some heuristics to present a decent page for you. On the other hand if you hit some IP address, you might just hit the server hosted on IP, that might have these fancy stuff to give you back.

This is just a speculation from me. Someone can correct me if i'm wrong.